# Python selenium webdriver click() does not work properly

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new in Python. I am building a Instagram bot with help of a Youtube tutorial.

I am trying to login to my account and then from there navigate to a user.
But the click() does not seem to work properly.
It goes to the login page, fills in the username and password and clicks on the login button and navigates to the user without logging me in (just like when you open a user's profile without logging in to your account).

The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        self.base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com'
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.get('{}/'.format(self.base_url))
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]').click() 
        **That click() does not have any effect **


    def nav_user(self, user):
        self.driver.get('{}/{}/'.format(self.base_url , user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
ig_bot=InstagramBot('my_username' , 'my_password')
ig_bot.nav_user('garyvee') **navigates me to garyvee without logging me in**  
time.sleep(100)
```

And when I do not use that *nav_user* function, the click() works properly and logs me in.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication process takes a few moments. You can put another "sleep" after clicking the button and then it works.

```
def login(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.driver.get('{}/'.format(self.base_url))
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]').click()
    time.sleep(5)    # <--- adjust to your needs
```